# Fit a quadratic form given covariant derivatives on the sphere?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, differential-geometry

I am trying to solve for a particular vector given covariant first and second derivative for a function on a sphere.  If you have a quadratic form restricted to the sphere:

$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^T\Gamma x + p^T x + c,\, x\in S^{n-1}$

then the covariant first and second derivatives at $x$ take the form:

$\nabla f(x) = P_x(\Gamma x + p)$

$\nabla^2 f(x) = P_x\Gamma P_x-(p^Tx+x^T\Gamma x)P_x$

where $P_x = (I-xx^T)$ is the projection operator onto the tangent space at $x$.  Suppose $\Gamma$ is symmetric, $\Gamma p = 0$ and $\mathrm{Tr}(\Gamma) = 0$.  If we know $f, \nabla f$ and $ \nabla^2 f$ at a particular point, can we solve for $p$?  Is the solution unique?

---

**Edit** After some numerical experimentation I realized the expression I gave for $\nabla^2 f$ is wrong.  Since the second derivative should map one point in the tangent space to another point in the tangent space, the factor of $I$ in the second term should be replaced with $P_x$.  Since $\mathrm{Tr}(P_x) = n-1$, $\mathrm{Tr}(\nabla^2 f) = -(n-1)p^Tx - nx^T\Gamma x$, but now $x^T\nabla^2 f x = 0$ and the argument below fails. Technically I believe this makes $\nabla^2 f$ the Hessian and not the second covariant derivative.

Comment: If $x$ and $\Gamma x$ are known as well, we have $p = -\nabla^2 f(x)x + \nabla f(x) - \Gamma x$.

Comment: $x$ is known but $\Gamma x$ isn't.

Comment: Why the complication with the pseudoinverse; why not just use $p=\nabla f-\Gamma x=\nabla f-\nabla^2 f x$?

Comment: Good question...because I like making things more complicated than they need to be?  I fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

**Complete revision of the complete rewrite:**

Let $P_x = I - x \otimes x$ denote the projection onto the tangent space $T_x S^{n-1}$ to $S^{n-1}$ at $x$. Then
$$
 p = P_x p + (I-P_x)p = P_x p + \left\langle p,x\right\rangle x,
$$
so that solving for $p$ is the same as solving for $P_x p$ and for $\left\langle p,x\right\rangle$. Before continuing, let's rewrite what we know:
\begin{align*}
 f(x) &= \tfrac{1}{2}\left\langle x,\Gamma x\right\rangle + \left\langle p,x\right\rangle + c\\
 \nabla f(x) &= P_x (\Gamma x + p)\\
 \nabla^2 f(x) &= P_x \Gamma P_x - \left(\left\langle p,x \right\rangle + \left\langle x,\Gamma x\right\rangle\right) P_x.
\end{align*}

Let us first solve for $\left\langle p,x \right\rangle$ and $\left\langle x,\Gamma x\right\rangle$ in terms of $c$. The condition $\operatorname{Tr}(\Gamma)= 0$ gives us:
\begin{align*}
 0 &= \operatorname{Tr}(\Gamma)\\ &= \operatorname{Tr}(P_x \Gamma P_x) + \operatorname{Tr}((x \otimes x)\Gamma(x \otimes x))\\
 &= \operatorname{Tr}\left(\nabla^2 f(x) + (\left\langle p,x\right\rangle + \left\langle x,\Gamma x \right\rangle)P_x\right) + \operatorname{Tr}\left(\left\langle x,\Gamma x,\right\rangle x \otimes x\right)\\
 &=\operatorname{Tr}(\nabla^2 f(x))+(n-1)\left\langle p,x\right\rangle + n\left\langle x,\Gamma x\right\rangle.
\end{align*}
Combining with our expression for $f(x)$, we find that
$$
 \begin{pmatrix} \tfrac{1}{2} & 1 & 1 \\ n & n-1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \left\langle x,\Gamma x\right\rangle \\ \left\langle p,x\right\rangle \\ c \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} f(x) \\ -\operatorname{Tr}(\nabla^2 f(x)) \end{pmatrix},
$$
which admits the solution, treating $c$ as a free variable,
$$
  \begin{pmatrix} \left\langle x,\Gamma x\right\rangle \\ \left\langle p,x\right\rangle \end{pmatrix} = c \frac{1}{n+1} \begin{pmatrix} 2n-2 \\ -2n \end{pmatrix} + \frac{1}{n+1} \begin{pmatrix} -2n+2 & 2 \\ 2n & -1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} f(x) \\ -\operatorname{Tr}(\nabla^2 f(x)) \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Let us now look at $P_x p$ and $P_x \Gamma x$. By the expression for $\nabla f(x)$, we at least have that
$$ P_x \Gamma x + P_x p = \nabla f(x).$$
Now, since $0 = \Gamma p = \Gamma P_x p + \left\langle p,x\right\rangle \Gamma x$, it follows that
\begin{align*}
0 &= P_x \Gamma p \\
&= P_x \Gamma P_x P_x p + \left\langle p,x\right\rangle P_x \Gamma x\\
&= \left(\nabla^2 f(x) + \left(\left\langle p,x\right\rangle + \left\langle x,\Gamma x \right\rangle\right) P_x\right) P_x p + \left\langle p,x\right\rangle P_x \Gamma x\\
&= \left(\nabla^2 f(x) + \left(\left\langle p,x\right\rangle + \left\langle x,\Gamma x \right\rangle\right) P_x \right) P_x p + \left\langle p,x \right\rangle P_x \Gamma x.
\end{align*}
Hence,
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \nabla^2 f(x) + \left(\left\langle p,x\right\rangle + \left\langle x,\Gamma x \right\rangle\right) P_x & \left\langle p,x\right\rangle P_x \\ P_x & P_x \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} P_x p \\ P_x \Gamma x \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \nabla f(x) \end{pmatrix},
$$
which is equivalent by an elementary row operation to
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \nabla^2 f(x) & -\left\langle x,\Gamma x\right\rangle P_x \\ P_x & P_x \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} P_x p \\ P_x \Gamma x \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -\left(\left\langle p,x\right\rangle + \left\langle x,\Gamma x \right\rangle\right) \nabla f(x) \\ \nabla f(x) \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Thus if $\nabla^2 f(x)$ is invertible on $T_x S^{n-1}$ and if 
$$
 P_x + \left\langle x,\Gamma x\right\rangle \left(\nabla^2 f(x) \right)^{-1}
$$
is invertible  on $T_x S^{n-1}$, then you can use the formula for blockwise inversion to solve for $P_x p$ and $P_x \Gamma x$, given your values of $\left\langle p,x\right\rangle$ and $\left\langle x,\Gamma x\right\rangle$. I'm now at a loss, however, as to how pin down $c$, given that every bit of given information really has been used.

Comment: The particular form of $\Gamma$ given here is motivated by the log likelihood of the Kent distribution, which generalizes the von Mises distribution to the sphere.  The conditions that $tr(\Gamma) = 0$ and $||\Gamma||<||p||/2$ I believe are required to make sure that $\nabla^2 f$ is positive definite at $p$ and negative definite at $-p$ and might not actually be needed for solving for $p$.  Perhaps either $\Gamma p = 0$ or $\nabla f(x_0)$ could be useful when $c$ isn't known?

Comment: Are you assuming, then, that $p$ lies on the sphere? Because that might be useful for getting additional equations.

Comment: No, $p$ is unconstrained except that it is in the null space of $\Gamma$.  $p/||p||$ is the mean of the Kent distribution, while $||p||$ is the concentration.

Comment: Alright, I'm pretty sure that the conditions I mentioned in the first comment are superfluous and I removed them.

Comment: Also I think you have a sign flipped in $\langle x, \nabla^2 f x \rangle$.  I get $-\langle p, x \rangle - \langle x, \Gamma x \rangle$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out---one gets a slightly simpler expression for $\left\langle p,x\right\rangle$ than before, as a result. Given the algebra, it seems to me that the expressions for $\nabla f(x)$ and $\nabla^2 f(x)$ combine to give user1551's expression $p = -\Gamma x + \nabla f(x) - \nabla^2 f(x)x$ and no more, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: As it turns out, one can actually solve for all of $\left\langle p,x\right\rangle$, $\left\langle x,\Gamma x\right\rangle$, and $c$, all at once, using the fact that $\Gamma$ is traceless. As for how to figure out $P_x p$ and $P_x \Gamma x$, I've no clue at the moment.

Comment: @DavidPfau I've completed my solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7587/discussion-between-david-pfau-and-branimir-cacic)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a dirty, inelegant, brute-force approach. Let $e_1=(1,0,\ldots,0)^T$, $Q$ be a real orthogonal matrix with $x$ as its first column (i.e. $Qe_1=x$), $\Lambda=Q^T\Gamma Q$ and $q=Q^Tp$.
\begin{align}
g := Q^T\nabla f(x) &= (I-e_1e_1^T)(\Lambda e_1 + q),\tag{1}\\
H = Q^T\left(\nabla^2 f(x)\right)Q
&= (I-e_1e_1^T)\Lambda(I-e_1e_1^T)-(q^Te_1+e_1^T\Lambda e_1)I,\tag{2}\\
\Lambda q &= 0,\tag{3}\\
\operatorname{tr}\Lambda &= 0.\tag{4}
\end{align}
Now write $\Lambda=\begin{pmatrix}a&b^T\\b&D\end{pmatrix},\ g=\begin{pmatrix}g_1\\ \tilde{g}\end{pmatrix}$ and $q=\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\end{pmatrix}$ where $a,u\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $(1)-(2)$ give
\begin{align}
g_1 &= 0,\tag{5}\\
\tilde{g} &= b+v,\tag{6}\\
H &= \begin{pmatrix}-(a+u)\\&D-(a+u)I\end{pmatrix},\tag{7}\\
\end{align}
From $(7)$, we obtain $h_{11}=-(a+u)$ and in turn $D$ is the trailing $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ submatrix of $H-h_{11}I$. So, by $(4)$, we get $a=-\operatorname{tr}D$ and hence
\begin{equation}
u=\operatorname{tr}D-h_{11}.\tag{8}
\end{equation}
It remains to solve for $v$. From $(3)$, we get
\begin{align}
au+b^Tv&=0,\\
bu+Dv&=0.
\end{align}
Let $w=v-\frac12\tilde{g}$. Rearrange $(6)$ to $b=\frac12\tilde{g}-w$ and substitute the result into the above, we get
\begin{align*}
au+\left(\frac12\tilde{g}-w\right)^T\left(w+\frac12\tilde{g}\right)&=0,\\
\left(\frac12\tilde{g}-w\right)u+D\left(w+\frac12\tilde{g}\right)&=0.
\end{align*}
These can be further rewritten as
\begin{align}
\|w\|^2 &= au + \frac14\|\tilde{g}\|^2,\tag{9}\\
(uI-D)w &= \frac12(uI+D)\tilde{g}.\tag{10}
\end{align}
**Edit:** Therefore $w$ (or $v$) is solvable if and only if $g$ satisfies $(5)$, $H$ has the block diagonal form in $(7)$, equation $(10)$ (with $u$ given by $(8)$) has a unique solution $w$ and this solution satisfies $(9)$, or $(10)$ has infinitely many solution and
\begin{equation}
\|(uI-D)^\dagger (uI+D)\tilde{g}\|^2 \le -4(h_{11}+u)u + \|\tilde{g}\|^2. \tag{11}
\end{equation}
The solution is unique iff equality holds.

Comment: Nice.  I may attempt a cleaned-up version of this, but for now a few observations: $a = x^T\Gamma x$, $u = p^Tx$, $\mathrm{tr}D = \mathrm{tr}(I-xx^T)\Gamma(I-xx^T)$.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to derive a near-solution that doesn't require knowledge of $c$ as in Branimir's solution.  At least I can reduce it to an equation that depends only on $p^T x$ and $P_x p$ and is easy to solve for one given the other.  However I don't know if there is any method to solve for both simultaneously.

From the condition $\mathrm{Tr}(\Gamma) = 0$, we have:

$\mathrm{Tr}\nabla^2 f = -(n-1)(p^T x) - n(x^T\Gamma x)$

If we knew $P_x p$ and $p^Tx$ we could reconstruct $\Gamma$ as follows:

$\Gamma = P_x\Gamma P_x + xx^T\Gamma P_x + P_x\Gamma xx^T + xx^T\Gamma xx^T \\
= (\nabla^2 f+\frac{p^T x-\mathrm{Tr}\nabla^2 f}{n}P_x) + (\nabla f-P_xp)x^T + x(\nabla f - P_x p)^T - \frac{\mathrm{Tr}\nabla^2 f+(n-1)p^T x}{n}xx^T$

and plugging this in to $(\Gamma p)^T(\Gamma p)=0$ gives us:

$||\nabla^2 f P_xp + \frac{p^Tx-\mathrm{Tr}(\nabla^2f)}{n}P_xp + p^Tx(\nabla f - P_xp)||^2 \\
+ ||(P_xp)^T(\nabla f - P_xp)x-\frac{(n-1)(p^Tx)+\mathrm{Tr}(\nabla^2 f)}{n}(p^Tx)x||^2 = 0$

Since the norm squared is always positive, both terms must be zero, giving us the conditions:

$\left(\nabla^2 f - \frac{n-1}{n}(p^Tx)P_x-\frac{\mathrm{Tr}(\nabla^2f)}{n}P_x\right)p + (p^Tx)\nabla f = 0$

and

$p^T(P_x p - \nabla f)+\frac{p^Tx}{n}\left(\mathrm{Tr}(\nabla^2 f)+(n-1)p^Tx\right)=0$

Given $p^Tx$, the first equation is a linear function of $P_xp$, and given $P_xp$, the second equation is a quadratic function of $p^Tx$.  However, I am at a loss as to how to solve for them simultaneously, and any help is welcome.  If we solve for $P_xp$ and plug the solution into the second equation, we get an equation of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311044/solve-a-quadratic-matrix-equation) form, which doesn't seem to admit an analytic solution.  Numerically, Newton's method doesn't seem to converge, so now I'm at a loss.