# Solve a quadratic matrix equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, roots

Given a known symmetric matrix $M$, vector $\vec{v}$ and scalars $a$ and $b$, I'm trying to solve for a scalar $x$ such that:

$\vec{v}^T(M+(ax+b)I)^{-1}\vec{v} - x\vec{v}^T(M+(ax+b)I)^{-2}\vec{v}-(ax+b) = 0$

Is there any hope for an analytic solution, or should I just resort to something like Newton's method?

Comment: what is that $()^{-2}$ meaning at the matrix? As you only have bunch of quadratic equations there will be an analytic solution

Comment: It's an invertible matrix, so that's the square of the inverse

Answer (score 1):

There's some hope. Let $w_i$ be an eigenvector of $M$, with eigenvalue $\lambda_i$. Then $$[M+(ax+b)I]w_i = [\lambda_i + (ax+b)]w_i.$$ So if $\alpha_i = v\cdot w_i$, your equation becomes
$$\sum_i \frac{\alpha_i^2}{\lambda_i + (ax+b)} - x\sum_i \frac{\alpha_i^2}{[\lambda_i + (ax+b)]^2} - (ax+b) = 0$$
$$\sum_i \frac{\alpha_i^2[(a-1)x+\lambda_i+b]}{(ax+\lambda_i+b)^2} - (ax+b) = 0,$$
with the LHS a rational function in $x$. I doesn't look like there's an easy closed-form formula for its roots, unless there's something special about the spectrum of $M$.

Comment: No, there isn't any particular structure to the spectrum of M.  Short of an analytic solution, are there algorithmic methods suited to finding roots of rational functions like this one?

Comment: You can clear out the denominator to get a polynomial; unfortunately it's high-dimensional ($2n-1$). If you only need one root Newton's method might be best. How did this problem arise? Maybe there's some way of teasing out extra structure?

Comment: This problem came from trying to solve this problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307623/fit-a-quadratic-form-given-covariant-derivatives-on-the-sphere.  In my partial solution I show how I got to an equation of this form.

Comment: I suppose there is slightly more structure.  $b$ is $-\mathrm{Tr}M/n = -\sum_i \lambda_i/n$ where $n$ is the dimension of the matrix, and $a = \frac{n-1}{n}$.  So that might simplify the numerator considerably.

Answer (score 0):

For the more restricted case that motivated this question, we know that $a=\frac{n-1}{n}$, where $\vec{v}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $M\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $b = -\mathrm{Tr}M/n$.  Then the rational equation given in user7530's solution simplifies to

$\displaystyle\sum_i \frac{\alpha_i^2\left(-x+n\lambda_i-\sum_i \lambda_i\right)}{\left((n-1)x+n\lambda_i-\sum_i \lambda_i\right)^2} = (n-1)x-\sum_i \lambda_i$